# Image loading issue on html page

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

[image]

See above image,
When I refresh the page, the image is not loading but If I change tab from MEN to WOMEN and WOMEN to MEN then image will be display.
Even If I change anything in the CSS then also image will be display.
Unable to get why image is not display directly.

Other images display correctly as required but some of the images I'm getting this type of problem.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Seeing your code for your view and controllers would be very helpful.

Comment: Seems, You didnt set width and height for image which is not displaying. Set width and height and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the height of the image or may be with the height of its parent div.

```
height: 100%;
width: auto;
```

Just define the image height as a percentage, auto width will keep it in proportion.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, You didnt set width and height for image which is not displaying. Set width and height and try.

The image height is showing 2px. so need to set height for image.

Answer (score 0):

Please set width*height to img tag

Example :

```
<img src="image.png" width="350" height="350" />
```

There is 340px*2px width and height you can see in image given by you.